# Post Request in .ts not waiting for response

Tags: angular, typescript, post, request, response

ABCController.ts

```
this.ABCService.CreateFile(
      this.FileData
      ).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.info.code == "200") {
        alert("File successfully generated");
       }
      if (data.info.code == "400") {
        alert("Error while generating the subscription file");
       }
       
    });
```

ABCService.ts

```
 CreateFile(data: abcModel): Observable<ApiResponseModel> {
     this._base = `${environment.api.baseUrl}abc/CreateFile`;
    
     return  this._http.post<ApiResponseModel>(this._base, data);
   }
```

The File gets generated in controller and response also sent..when i wait in debugging then the response comes(for eg. data.info.code ="200"

Why reponse not received and received while waiting and debugging

Comment: You added the debugging code, which is looks fine and according to your statements is working as expected. Could you please add the non-debugging code which is **not** working?